# How to get a user's account picture in Linux?

Tags: debian, gnome, users, images, accounts

How can I get a user's login image or avatar or 'dp' in Linux? A lot of similar questions on SO provide answer for Windows,not for Linux. [Im on Debian 10, GNOME DE, but prefer a general solution if possible]

Comment: I'm not convinced that "user's account picture" is a Thing in Linux, but `getent passwd $USER` is a start.

Comment: In my application, I want to keep the user's pic instead of their name (like in websites) :p

Comment: @waltinator Im able to get the user's home, what to do with that? But, please tell me, is the account picture a property by OS or Login Manager (like GDM etc.?)

Comment: I repeat "Account Picture" is a nonexistent thing in Unix. One could, by administrative fiat, compel your users to provide an image, but that's on you.

Comment: You can install "Mugshot" program, which does that for you, but it's a rather GUI solution. Well it doesn't actually update /etc/passwd or anything like that. It just integrates your information with GTK. You can use `gsettings list-keys apps.mugshot` (assume you have mugshot installed) to list the keys, and you can update info from CLI as well. This info is integrated to your DE, like XFCE.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out in comments, there is no such concept of an "account picture" in Linux, per se.  Any kind of "account picture" concept would have to be provided either by whatever desktop you're using, or some other add-on software.

If you happen to be using GNOME as your desktop, it stores information about where to find a user's account picture (in the `Icon` config value) in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/{username}`, as pointed out in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61637/where-is-the-users-profile-picture-stored-in-gnome-3) on the Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange forum (where `{username}` is the name of the user you're inquiring about); the default location is a file called `.face` in the user's home directory (as is also pointed out in another answer).  If you're using a different desktop than GNOME (e.g., KDE), it may store account pictures, or pointers to account pictures, elsewhere.  If you're on a server that has no desktop installed, there most likely won't be any account pictures anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success storing a 300 to 400 pixels height/width JPEG picture as `.face` in the user's home directory:

```
$ identify .face
.face JPEG 351x351 351x351+0+0 8-bit sRGB 16847B 0.000u 0:00.001
```